How to drag & drop (move) GtkWindow using GtkGestureClick on a child widget?
I am trying to drag and drop(move) the GtkWindow on the screen, by clicking(& holding) on its child widget. This is my script, which is working, but it shows warning when compiling: 'gtk_widget_translate_coordinates' deprecated: use 'gtk_widget_compute_point' instead.
Can someone tell me how to implement the gtk_widget_compute_point function?
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
start_move (GtkGestureClick *gesture,
            int n_press,
            double x,
            double y,
            gpointer   data)
{
  GtkWidget *widget = gtk_event_controller_get_widget (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
  GdkSurface *surface;
  GdkEvent *event;
  guint button;
  guint32 timestamp;

  gtk_gesture_set_state (GTK_GESTURE (gesture), GTK_EVENT_SEQUENCE_CLAIMED);
  surface = gtk_native_get_surface (gtk_widget_get_native (widget));
  event = gtk_event_controller_get_current_event (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
  if (gdk_event_get_event_type (event) == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS)
    button = gdk_button_event_get_button (event);
  else
    button = 0;
  timestamp = gdk_event_get_time (event);
  gtk_widget_translate_coordinates (widget, GTK_WIDGET (gtk_widget_get_root (widget)), x, y, &x, &y);
  gdk_toplevel_begin_move (GDK_TOPLEVEL (surface), gdk_event_get_device (event), button, x, y, timestamp);
  gtk_event_controller_reset (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
}


static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "example");

  GtkWidget *fixed = gtk_fixed_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child ((GtkWindow    *)window, fixed);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (fixed, 400, 200);

  GtkWidget *c_btn = gtk_button_new_from_icon_name ("window-close-symbolic");
  gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (fixed), c_btn, 125, 90);


    GtkGesture *gesture;
    gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
    g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (start_move), NULL);
    gtk_widget_add_controller (c_btn, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));


  gtk_window_present ((GtkWindow*)window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}


The gtk_widget_compute_pointfunction use graphene_point_t, a data structure capable of describing a point with two coordinates:
graphene_point_t.x

graphene_point_t.y

The simplest method of switching the given program therefore seems to me to be as follows.
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
start_move (GtkGestureClick *gesture,
            int n_press,
            double x,
            double y,
            gpointer   data)
{
  GtkWidget *widget = gtk_event_controller_get_widget (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
  GdkSurface *surface;
  GdkEvent *event;
  guint button;
  guint32 timestamp;
  // added
  const graphene_point_t *point = graphene_point_init (graphene_point_alloc (), x, y);
  graphene_point_t *point1 = graphene_point_init (graphene_point_alloc (), x, y);

  gtk_gesture_set_state (GTK_GESTURE (gesture), GTK_EVENT_SEQUENCE_CLAIMED);
  surface = gtk_native_get_surface (gtk_widget_get_native (widget));
  event = gtk_event_controller_get_current_event (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
  if (gdk_event_get_event_type (event) == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS)
    button = gdk_button_event_get_button (event);
  else
    button = 0;
  timestamp = gdk_event_get_time (event);
  // changed
  gboolean a =gtk_widget_compute_point (widget, GTK_WIDGET (gtk_widget_get_root (widget)),point,point1);
  gdk_toplevel_begin_move (GDK_TOPLEVEL (surface), gdk_event_get_device (event), button, x, y, timestamp);
  gtk_event_controller_reset (GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));
  // added
  graphene_point_free(point1);
  free((void*)point);
}


static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "example");

  GtkWidget *fixed = gtk_fixed_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child ((GtkWindow    *)window, fixed);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (fixed, 400, 200);

  GtkWidget *c_btn = gtk_button_new_from_icon_name ("window-close-symbolic");
  gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (fixed), c_btn, 125, 90);


    GtkGesture *gesture;
    gesture = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
    g_signal_connect (gesture, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (start_move), NULL);
    gtk_widget_add_controller (c_btn, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture));


  gtk_window_present ((GtkWindow*)window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}

Have fun programming

It is not working as expected. As soon as the child widget is clicked, the mouse pointer moves to the  0x0 (xy) position.

Just checked it again. For me, both versions work the same.

Not working properly on xfce, Linux Lite 7

sorry, I use Ubuntu 24.04
